# How to calculate a column from Listview columns and add it to that Listview?

Tags: c#, sql-server, listview

I want to retrieve the following Table from SQL to display in Listview

```
Admission ID, Room No,   Admit Date,   Discharge Date,   Daily Charges, 
 1             001       2018-06-22    2018-06-29        3000                  
 2             002       2018-06-23    2018-06-25        2500
```

I want to add two further columns Days and Total Charges. 
The Days columns should show the days between the admit and discharge dates and total charges should be the Multiplication of Days and daily charges.

The desire Listview is:

```
 Room ID,   Room No,  Admit,       Discharge,    Daily charges,  Days,  Total

 1          001       2018-06-22    2018-06-29    3000            8      24000 
 2          002       2018-06-23    2018-06-25    2500            4      10000

                                                         Grand Total:    34000
```

Here is my code

```
        listView1.GridLines = false;
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
```

//Add Column Header

```
        listView4.Columns.Add("Room ID", 80);
        listView4.Columns.Add("Room No", 80);
        listView4.Columns.Add("Admit Date", 90);
        listView4.Columns.Add("Discharged Date", 90);
        listView4.Columns.Add("Daily Charges", 90);
        listView4.Columns.Add("Stayed Days", 80);
        listView4.Columns.Add("Total Charges", 80);

        string sql = " SELECT dbo.admission.admission_id, dbo.Room.Room_No, dbo.admission.in_date, dbo.admission.out_date, dbo.Room.daily_charges FROM dbo.admission INNER JOIN dbo.Room ON dbo.admission.Room_id = dbo.Room.Room_id WHERE (P_id = '" + textBox1.Text + "')";
        SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(cs);
        cnn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn);
        SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        listView4.Items.Clear();

        while (Reader.Read())
        {
            ListViewItem lv1 = new ListViewItem(Reader.GetInt32(0).ToString());
            lv1.SubItems.Add(Reader.GetString(1).ToString());
            lv1.SubItems.Add(Reader.GetDateTime(2).ToString());
            lv1.SubItems.Add(Reader.GetDateTime(3).ToString());
            lv1.SubItems.Add(Reader.GetDecimal(4).ToString());

            DateTime sDate, eDate;
            Decimal daily = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < listView4.Items.Count; i++)
            {


                ListViewItem item = listView4.SelectedItems[i];
                //fill the text boxes

                sDate = DateTime.Parse(listView4.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
                eDate = DateTime.Parse(listView4.Items[i].SubItems[4].Text);

                String diff2 = (eDate - sDate).TotalDays.ToString();
                daily = decimal.Parse(listView4.Items[i].SubItems[6].Text);

                string[] row = { diff2,daily.ToString() };


            }


            listView4.Items.Add(lv1);


        }

        Reader.Close();
        cnn.Close();

        decimal totalDoctorCharges = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listView4.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            totalDoctorCharges += decimal.Parse(listView4.Items[i].SubItems[6].Text);
        }
        textBox3.Text = totalDoctorCharges.ToString();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I refuse to stay at your hotel/hospital if you charge me for 4 days when I stay from 2018-06-23  to  2018-06-25! Is there some business rule you haven't mentioned or is this just a slip of the key?

Comment: In your Select statement, what is P_id ?

Answer (score 0):

I created a class to store the values form the database and provided the calculated values. Then a DataAccess class to separate the database work from the user interface

```
public class HospitalAdmission
    {
        //The custom constructor sets all the properties including the calculated valuew.
        public HospitalAdmission(int id, string roomNum, DateTime dateIn, DateTime dateOut, decimal dayRate)
        {
            ID = id;
            RoomNum = roomNum;
            In = dateIn;
            Out = dateOut;
            DayRate = dayRate;
            LengthOfStay = Out.Subtract(In).Days;
            TotalFee = DayRate * LengthOfStay;
        }
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string RoomNum { get; set; }  
        public DateTime In { get; set; }
        public DateTime Out { get; set; }
        public decimal DayRate { get; set; }
        public int LengthOfStay { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalFee;
    }
    public class DataAccess
    {
        public List<HospitalAdmission> lstHosAdmin = new List<HospitalAdmission>();
        public void GetData()
        {
            //I am not very sure of your select statement. Please check it in SSMS
            //P_id will have to be a column in one of your tables, qualify it with the table name as you have done for the other fields
            string sql = " SELECT dbo.admission.admission_id, dbo.Room.Room_No, dbo.admission.in_date, dbo.admission.out_date, dbo.Room.daily_charges FROM dbo.admission INNER JOIN dbo.Room ON dbo.admission.Room_id = dbo.Room.Room_id WHERE P_id = @pid;";
            //using ensures that you objects are closed and disposed even if there is an error
            using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection("Your connection string"))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, cnn))
                {
                    //Always use parameters to prevent Sql Injection
                    //I assumed P_id was a VarChar because it was surronded by quotes check the db for correct datatype
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@pid", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = textBox1.Text;
                    cnn.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader Reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (Reader.Read())
                        {
                            //calls the custom constructor passing in the values from the database
                            HospitalAdmission ha = new HospitalAdmission(Reader.GetInt32(0),Reader.GetString(1),Reader.GetDateTime(2), Reader.GetDateTime(3),Reader.GetDecimal(4));
                            lstHosAdmin.Add(ha);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private List<HospitalAdmission> lstHA
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataAccess da = new DataAccess();
            da.GetData();
            lstHA = da.lstHosAdmin;
            FillListView();
        }
        private void FillListView()
        {
            listView4.GridLines = false;
            listView4.View = View.Details;
            listView4.FullRowSelect = true;
            //Add Column Header
            listView4.Columns.Add("Room ID", 80);
            listView4.Columns.Add("Room No", 80);
            listView4.Columns.Add("Admit Date", 90);
            listView4.Columns.Add("Discharged Date", 90);
            listView4.Columns.Add("Daily Charges", 90);
            listView4.Columns.Add("Stayed Days", 80);
            listView4.Columns.Add("Total Charges", 80);
            listView4.BeginUpdate();
            foreach (HospitalAdmission ha in lstHA)
            { 
            ListViewItem lv1 = new ListViewItem(ha.ID.ToString());
            lv1.SubItems.Add(ha.RoomNum.ToString());
            lv1.SubItems.Add(ha.In.ToString());
            lv1.SubItems.Add(ha.Out.ToString());
            lv1.SubItems.Add(ha.DayRate.ToString());
            lv1.SubItems.Add(ha.LengthOfStay.ToString());
            lv1.SubItems.Add(ha.TotalFee.ToString());
            listView4.items.Add(lv1);
            }
            listView4.EndUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```